# BeautifulSoup TypeError

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I'm running into an issue with BeautifulSoup (more specifically the xml parser) where it appears that having "name" as a tag attribute is overloading some underlying function.

Given the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

siteconfig="""
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sites version="180201">
  <site name="au" location="oceana">
    <addresslist="IPv4">
      <address>192.168.1.10/32</address>
      <address>192.168.2.10/32</address>
    </addresslist>
    <addresslist="IPv6">
      <address>fc00:07bc:5ae6:75d0::26/128</address>
      <address>fc00:07bc:5ae6:75d1::26/128</address>
    </addresslist>
  </site>
  <site name="us" location="americas">
    <addresslist="IPv4">
      <address>192.168.4.13/32</address>
      <address>192.168.5.13/32</address>
    </addresslist>
    <addresslist="IPv6">
      <address>fc00:07bc:5ae6:75d0::45/128</address>
      <address>fc00:07bc:5ae6:75d1::45/128</address>
    </addresslist>
  </site>
</sites>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(siteconfig,"xml")
print(soup.find("site", name="us"))
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./siteConfig.py", line 33, in <module>
    print(soup.find("site", name="us"))
TypeError: find() got multiple values for argument 'name'
```

But if I change the last line to be:

```
print(soup.find("site", location="americas"))
```

I get the following output:

```
<site location="americas" name="us">
  <addresslist>="IPv4"&gt;
    <address>192.168.4.13/32</address>
    <address>192.168.5.13/32</address>
  </addresslist>
  <addresslist>="IPv6"&gt;
    <address>fc00:07bc:5ae6:75d0::45/128</address>
    <address>fc00:07bc:5ae6:75d1::45/128</address>
  </addresslist>
</site>
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`name` is the name of the first parameter to `find` (in your case, "site"):

> find(name=None, attrs={}, recursive=True, text=None, **kwargs) method of bs4.BeautifulSoup instance

Use an attribute dictionary `soup.find("site", {"name":"us"})` to avoid the collision.

Comment: And great explanation - I can see now what was causing the error